# Ubuntu mail server switch to Postfix from Sendmail

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail

Sendmail is running as default as mail server on Ubuntu. How to switch to postfix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have extensive experience with Postfix.

The quickest and easiest way to do this on Ubuntu is:

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

This will remove sendmail (it will install a version appropriate for postfix).

You will then need to configure postfix.

Do you also have questions about configuration?

To have *decent* settings choose "internet site" during the installation process.

You can get away with a config file as short as this:

**sudo nano /etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
myhostname = mail.somesite.com

mydestination = $myhostname

myorigin = $myhostname

relay_domains = $myhostname
```

Be very, very careful about avoiding setting up an open relay server.  You'll quickly get blacklisted.

Comment: You can also define mydomain but postfix is smart enough to get this info from myhostname.  If you server hostname is something other then the domain from which you want to send email you would then want to define mydomain.

Comment: Chances are you'll also need to manually `sudo service sendmail stop` either before or after you run the install command. Apt will remove the sendmail service, but won't necessarily stop it.

Comment: I've also found that Postfix doesn't completely remove all of sendmail (specifically, the MSP part is still left running), resulting in failure notifications from broken cron jobs (see discussion [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557127)). I manually ran `apt-get purge sendmail-base sendmail-cf sendmail-bin` to clean things up.

Answer (score 2):

*Merely* to switch?

```
sudo apt-get remove sendmail
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

To do all the configurations afterwards? Not sure - I've not worked with postfix.

Comment: I would rather do this in ine command, like:
aptitude install sendmail- postfix
Otherwise all packages requiring a mailserver will be removed.